# String from C# to Python Throught WebSocket

Tags: c#, python, websocket

I have a WebSocket Server, which written in Python3.

```
server = WebsocketServer(13254, host='127.0.0.1')
server.set_fn_new_client(new_client)
server.set_fn_message_received(message_got)
server.run_forever()
```

And C# Client [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Websocket.Client/4.2.3?_src=template).

```
private async void Connect()
    {
        var exitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var url = new Uri($"wss://{ip}:{port.ToString()}");
        using (this.client = new WebsocketClient(url))
        {
            client.ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            client.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info =>
                Console.WriteLine($"Reconnection happened, type: {info.Type}"));

            client.MessageReceived.Subscribe(msg => Console.WriteLine($"Message received: {msg}"));

            await client.Start();

            exitEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    public async void send(string data)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => this.client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("A"))); 

    }
```

When I try to send some text, Server always crashes with `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 4: invalid start byte` error.

I tried:

- `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)` (Client)

But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It works. But I made mistake in `var url = new Uri($"wss://{ip}:{port.ToString()}");`
I spent about 6 hours and I read a lot of info about sockets and etc. and trouble was in 'S' LETTER. 'ws://'...